# How to post a status message to facebook with TO target using facebook4j?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook4j

I am using facebook4j to add fb page feed posting capabilities to an existing system. Initially I thought it would just be for posting to pages, which is done, but many pages don't allow posting. In such a case I need to fall back to targeting the individual in a status message. In facebook such a post shows up with heading like "{User's Name}‎ > {Target's Name}".

The problem I'm running into is that even though the facebook graph api has a "to" attribute for a message, I can not find a way to accomplish this with facebook4j. The postStatusMessage() method appears to only accept the id of the feed to post to and the PostUpdate class does not have a "to" property.  I could of course be misunderstanding what the arguments represent or how this should be accomplished.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't post to other people timeline using the API

Comment: I mean it is not possible at all

Comment: Then I'm not talking about posting to other people's timelines. We are adding functionality already made available by a competitor and I tried myself. I will get more info and update the question.